# not able to upload the file to web api

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web api project.in which i have done token based authentication successfully . but i am struggling to upload image to the web api.

i have following view

```
 <form data-bind="submit: uploadApi"> 

    <div>
        <label for="caption">Image Caption</label>
        <input name="caption" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="image1">Image File</label>
        <input name="image1" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I have used javascript code as follows

```
    self.uploadApi = function () {

    self.result('');

    var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    var headers = {};
    if (token) {
        headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

    }

    var data = new FormData();
    var file = self.imgPath();
    data.append('file', file);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Upload',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: headers,
        data:data
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("hai");
        self.result(data.FileName);
    }).fail(showError);



}
```

and my controller code is as follows

```
    [Route("api/Upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    [MimeMultipart]
    public async Task<FileUploadResult> Post()
    {
        var uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");

        var multipartFormDataStreamProvider = new UploadMultipartFormProvider(uploadPath);

        // Read the MIME multipart asynchronously 
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multipartFormDataStreamProvider);

        string _localFileName = multipartFormDataStreamProvider
            .FileData.Select(multiPartData => multiPartData.LocalFileName).FirstOrDefault();

        // Create response
        return new FileUploadResult
        {
            LocalFilePath = _localFileName,

            FileName = Path.GetFileName(_localFileName),

            FileLength = new FileInfo(_localFileName).Length
        };
    }
```

javascript able to  call the controller action (break points are fired).but not able to upload the image to folder
actually the controller code is copied from another project which uses the angular js.in angular js i used following code to call controller action

```
 $scope.startUploading = function ($files) {
        //$files: an array of files selected
        for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
            var $file = $files[i];
            alert($file);
            (function (index) {
                $scope.upload[index] = $upload.upload({
                    url: "./api/fileupload", // webapi url
                    method: "POST",
                    file: $file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    $scope.UploadedFiles.push({ FileName: data.FileName, FilePath: data.LocalFilePath, FileLength : data.FileLength });
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            })(i);
        }
    }
```

can any one sugest the proper arrangement in ajax request.

Comment: So, do you have any exception on server side? or alert is not called? what happened?

Comment: no exeption.but file is not uploaded to the folder

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday did the almost similar task. Following code might be helpful:

**JavaScript**

```
var formData = new FormData();            
var file = $('#fileUploader').prop('files');
formData.append("fileUploader", $("#fileUploader")[0].files[0]);
formData.append("DocumentID", $("#hdnDoc").val());

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'URL',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                })

})
```

**Web API**

```
public FileUploadResult Upload()
{
   HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
   using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
   {
       fileForDocumentStore.Document =      reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
   }

// you got file now, do your stuff.
}
```

Comment: can u please add code to upload the image to the folder